# Adding custom header to TIdHttp request, header value has commas

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy10

I'm using Delphi XE2 and Indy 10.5.8.0. I have an instance of TIdHttp and I need to add a custom header to the request. The header value has commas in it so it's getting parsed automatically into multiple headers. I don't want it to do that. I need the header value for my custom header to still be one string and not split based on a comma delimiter.

I have tried setting `IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Delimiter := ';'` with no success. Is there a way to make sure the header doesn't get split up?

```
procedure SendRequest;
const HeaderStr = 'URL-Encoded-API-Key VQ0_RV,ntmcOg/G3oA==,2012-06-13 16:25:19';
begin
  IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', HeaderStr);
  IdHttp1.Get(URL);
end;
```

Comment: IIRC you can do: IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Value['Authorization'] := HeaderStr; and so on for all "custom headers", don't forget about SSL!

Comment: Whether you use `AddValue()` or `Value[]`, the string ultimately ends up in `TIdHeaderList.FoldAndInsert()`, which is where the string gets parsed, split into pieces, and added to the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce this issue using the latest Indy 10.5.8 SVN snapshot.  The string you have shown gets assigned as a single line for me.

With that said, by default the `TIdHeaderList.FoldLines` property is set to True, and lines get folded on whitespace and comma characters, so that would explain why your string is getting split.  Near as I can tell, there have not been any logic changes made to the folding algorithm between your version of Indy and the latest version in SVN.

Comment: Setting FoldLines to False did the trick. The Indy documentation in Delphi says FoldLength is what forces the header value to wrap (not whitespace or commas) so I hadn't even bothered with folding. A great undocumented trick, thanks Remy!

Comment: The default value of the `TIdHeaderList.FoldLength` property is 78. The length of the final header you are adding is 75, so it should not be getting folded into multiple lines even with the `TIdHeaderList.FoldLines` property set to True. When I shorten the `TIdHeaderList.FoldLength` property to 74 or less, I see your line get folded as expected. So in your case, you could alterantively set the `FoldLength` to a higher value than 75 (if it is not already), or to `MaxInt` to disable folding a different way.

Comment: When a line is being folded, it gets folded at the whitespace/comma character that is closest to the `FoldLength` position of the line.

Comment: "*The default value of the `TIdHeaderList.FoldLength` property is 78*" - FYI, since Sept 2013, Indy now sets the default `FoldLength` to `MaxInt` in `TIdHTTP`, thus effectively disabling folding.