# Delphi Indy http.get with curl returns: unauthorized

Tags: http, delphi, curl, get, indy

According to the suppliers data i should have:

- Http type GET
- Response type: application/json
- Parameter: Authorization: bearer  + Token
- Curl: curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer + Token, 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/doors'
- Request URL: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/doors'

I have translated this to Delphi(Indy TidHttp):

```
procedure TForm42.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  resp: TMemoryStream;
begin
  resp := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Request.Clear;
    IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + TokenStr;
    IdHTTP1.Get('http://10.10.1.62:8080/api/v1/doors', resp);
    resp.Position := 0;
    memCall.Lines.LoadFromStream(resp);
  finally
    resp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I read a lot about it here, so finally i also added 'foldlines ([Adding custom header to TIdHttp request, header value has commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024262/adding-custom-header-to-tidhttp-request-header-value-has-commas))
I also tried 'X-Authorization' as parameter, something i read from R. Lebeau, but the only reaction i get is an errordialog saying '401 unauthorized'.

I'm sure about the Token string  (-> 'bearer ' + TokenStr) because i get an answer when putting the string in the suppliers trial.

Does someone have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.BasicAuthentication` should be `False` not `True` when using custom authentications.

And you don't need to set `CustomHeaders.FoldLines` as `TIdHTTP` already disables folding by default (it wasn't disabled by default at the time [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024262/) was posted).

Otherwise, the rest of the code looks fine.

Though, I would suggest specifying `TEncoding.UTF8` on the call to `LoadFromStream()`), eg:

```
procedure TForm42.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  resp: TMemoryStream;
begin
  resp := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Request.Clear;
    IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + TokenStr;
    IdHTTP1.Get('http://10.10.1.62:8080/api/v1/doors', resp);
    resp.Position := 0;
    memCall.Lines.LoadFromStream(resp, TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    resp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or, using the overload of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a `string`:

```
procedure TForm42.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdHTTP1.Request.Clear;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
  IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + TokenStr;
  memCall.Text := IdHTTP1.Get('http://10.10.1.62:8080/api/v1/doors');
end;
```